# xcode error when running application

Tags: iphone

target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework.static', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

I do have this error in Xcode.  some people say's to delete the XCworkpace. I am using Xcode4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and delete the XCWorkpace. I've done this quite a lot of times. 
Following are the steps:

1. Close your project in Xcode. Navigate into your xcodeproj package
   (either through Terminal, or in Finder by right-clicking and
   selecting "Show Package Contents")
2. Delete your XCWorkpace.
3. It will be re-created. Open your project in Xcode.

If you are worried just take a backup before doing it.